# htaccess file - can someone check it for me?

Tags: .htaccess

I've asked some to write a .htaccess file to go on my server. It is gobbledygook to me. Could someone check it for me?

I want it to do three things:

One. Redirect visits to xyz.co.uk to www.xyz.co.uk

Two. Redirect visits to http to https

(so that all visits go to https://www.xyz.co.uk and my Google Analytics isn't fragmented)

Three. Ensure the 404 page works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xyz.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.xyz.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xyz.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Thank you ever so much

Comment: It looks fine. Are you facing any problems?

Comment: It appears to work. I just wanted a second opinion because I can't understand the code. Thank you